# Google analytics shows most of the users quit the app on the first screen

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I'm trying to figure out why google analytics shows that most of the users (about 70%) won't even get past the First screen (Splash) when using my app, as shown in the following image:
[image: google analytics flow screenshot]

At first I thought the culprit was that the operations performed while the Splash screen is being shown were too slow, so users were just quitting the app.

But after several tests this doesn't seem to be the reason. (Since the Android counterpart of the app performs the same operations)

Then I came across the following google analytics documentation:

[Dispatching - iOS SDK](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/dispatch)

Which mentions 2 key points that might explain this behavior:

First,

> Data must be dispatched and received by 4 a.m. of the following day,
>   in the local time zone of each view. Any data received later than that
>   will not appear in reports.

Second,

> By default, data is dispatched from the Google Analytics SDK for iOS
>   every 2 minutes.

This makes me believe that what is actually happening is:

1. User launches the app
2. Goes to the main screen to receive the daily login bonus
3. Checks some other daily info
4. Sends the app to the background
5. DOES NOT launch the app until the next day.

What I would like to confirm is:

- Does google analytics always only sends the first even (in this case the splash screen being shown) and waits for 2 minutes before sending any others?
- Since the app was sent to the background within 2 minutes and not launched until the next day, does google analytics register it as the user quitting my app without moving from the splash screen?
- Is implementing the "Background dispatching" described in the document the recommended approach to solve this issue?

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this?

Comment: @bencallis no, sorry...